# I have a matrix dataset that I got from tfidfvectorizer method. How can I use this matrix to calculate the number of cluster(k) for clustering?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, k-means, tfidfvectorizer

Here is my matrix:
(0, 142)    0.5370878349040488
(0, 7984) 0.5513036540540609
(0, 4897) 0.47698105520883616
(0, 69)   0.21971894124922556
(0, 9644) 0.2700966789509706
(0, 6803) 0.17685900072454613
(0, 9366) 0.14485223742737366
(0, 2014) 0.08124103425955065

and so on

Here is my code. I randomly chose k = 30, but **I would like to find the value of k using elbow method. How can I code elbow method to calculate the value of k for my dataset?**

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',use_idf=True,max_features=None)
matrix = vec.fit_transform(corpus)
```

## KMeans clustering a kind of clustering.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

number_of_clusters=30
km = KMeans(n_clusters=number_of_clusters)




km.fit(matrix)
```

**Thank you!!**

Comment: Does my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so just loop over how many clusters you want to try out and append the `inertia_` also known as the `sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

number_of_clusters=30
wcss=[]
for i in range(1,number_of_clusters): 
     kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, random_state=0)
     kmeans.fit(matrix)
     wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

# Plot the elbow 
plt.plot(range(1,11),results)
plt.title('The Elbow Method Graph')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```